# replace in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can some one help me in this

I had a variable

```
var myValue = "what is you name? what is your age?"
```

i want to find the '?' in the string and replace it with a html input text element

where the user can enter the answer in the text box and at last i need a string as out put like this

"what is your name my name is xyz what is your age i am 25"

Please help me in this

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will dynamically take your myValue, replace all ?'s with inputs and then add a button to alert you of the user input. It will place myValue into the body, but you can place it somewhere else.

```
$(function() {
  var myValue = "what is you name? what is your age?";
  myValue = "<div>" + myValue;
  while(myValue.indexOf("?") > -1)
    myValue = myValue.replace("?", " <input type=\"text\" />");
  myValue += "</div>" + "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"sumUp(this)\">Declare</button>";
  $("body").html(myValue);
});

function sumUp(button) {
  var $prevDiv = $(button).prev().clone();
  $prevDiv.children("input").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).val());
  });
  alert($prevDiv.html());
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply first part worked fine.... i will be doing the send part and will let you know. Can you please give some description on the 2nd part the function part thanks kumar

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the help... I got the 2nd part too i understood it . Thanks for you help once again.

Kumar

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 input elements with IDs 'name' and 'age' respectively you can do this:

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById('name').value;
var ageValue = document.getElementById('age').value;
var anotherValue = myValue
      .replace(/name\?/, nameValue)
      .replace(/age\?/, ageValue)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply...i think i confused you all I am not sure what the text will be but it contains ? i want to replace that questions with a text box so when the user enter the input in those text box i need a string with the same string but instead of ? i need the text entered in the text box thanks kumar

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something as simple as:

```
var myValue = "what is you name? what is your age?"
var nameVar = window.prompt("What is your name?","");
var ageVar = window.prompt("What is your age?","");
var myValue = myValue.replace("?", nameVar).replace("?", ageVar);
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
var myValue = "what is you name? what is your age?"
var nameVar = '<input type="text" id="name" name="name">';
var ageVar = '<input type="text" id="age" name="age">';
document.write(myValue.replace("?", nameVar).replace("?", ageVar))
```

You'd then read the two input elements using jQuery with:

```
$('name').val();
$('age').val();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply...i think i confused you all I am not sure what the text will be but it contains ? i want to replace that questions with a text box so when the user enter the input in those text box i need a string with the same string but instead of ? i need the text entered in the text box thanks kumar

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div with the question in it:

```
<div id="questions">What is your name?  What is your age?</div>
```

and you want to replace those ? marks with input boxes, you could do this to make input boxes show up right after the questions:

```
var questions = $("#questions").text();
var questionMarkIndex = questions.indexOf("?");
var nameQuestion = questions.substring(0, questionMarkIndex+1);
var finalHtml = nameQuestion + '<input id="name" type="text" />';
var ageQuestion = questions.substring(questionMarkIndex+1);
finalHtml += ageQuestion + '<input id="age" type="text" />';
$("#questions").html(finalHtml);
```

This (or something close to it) will make you end up with `What is your name?[input box]  What is your age?[input box]`.